# Отсутствие взаимодействия WheelCollider с другими коллайдерами в Unity3D

Tags: unity3d, коллизии

Стандартный WheelCollider в Unity3D не взаимодействует с BoxCollider, из-за этого автомобиль колесом наполовину заезжает прямо в куб, можно ли как-либо исправить работу стандартного WheelCollider, а если нет, как сделать колеса с которыми такого не происходит?
[image: Скриншот происходящего с коллайдерами]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак это фишка `wheel` для оптимизации, `raycast` кидается из центра колеса вниз, чем больше радиус, тем больше колесо  входит в другие коллайдеры, пока не попадет под `raycast` Во многих играх такое есть, даже **ААА** класса. Выход один, делать свое колесо со своими проверками.
На `assetStore` есть старый проект от `UnityTechnologies`, `CarTutorial`, сделан на `unity3`, вот там хороший пример как реализовать свое колесо.

Также можно попробовать кидать свои доп. `raycast'ы` и смещать объект с wheel коллайдером, как вздумается.